# Android studio not hitting breakpoints on emulator

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I started with a clean installation and an Empty Activity with Java code

I am following this tutorial

https://medium.com/android-news/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

As you can see, the breakpoint is never activated when running the application

What is going on and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have launched your app without the Debugger attached. To launch with debugger hit the green bug icon next to the run icon while the app is stopped. Then a debugger will attach and you can use breakpoints!

Docs/Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#startdebug

Comment: I clicked the debug app (bug) icon. It seems to have stopped on the breakpoint, there is a blue line across it, but I dont see any step over or step into controls. There is no option to `step` in `Run` menu or anywhere else. I can step over with F8 or into with F7, but how do I continue to run to the next breakpoint?

Comment: When the Debugger is attached, a window should pop up with debug Info (from the bottom) and it has a column of buttons on the left. If you hover over them you can see what they do. The button to continue looks like half a pause and half a play button i believe (tho i am not sure atm) ⏏️ similar to this emoji just turned 90 deg